# Align elements on border of ellipse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a canvas with objects (product images, e.g. an apple) and I want elements to circle around them (icons, e.g. warnings about allegenes).

I've tried to add an Ellipse and now I want to align the icons on the border of the Ellipse. Is that possible? Hope you can help - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an ellipse, you just need to do the maths yourself.

You know how many elements you want to order so you calculate the positions using trigonometry and then set the position with:

```
element.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pos.Y);
element.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pos.X);
```

To calculate the positions, first calculate the angle between each object in the circle.

```
double radius = 100; // Or what ever your radius is
double angle = 360.0 / numItems * Math.PI / 180.0;
var centre = //position of product image

pos.X = centre.X +  Math.Cos(angle * itemNumber) * radius;
pos.Y = centre.Y +  Math.Sin(angle * itemNumber) * radius;
```

so you'll need a list or array of your elements and loop over that.